# Given-when-continue statement in perl

Tags: perl

I was learning Perl from [www.perltutorial.org](https://www.perltutorial.org/perl-given/). There I got to know that `given-when` is like `switch-case`. Hence to practice I wrote the below script. Now as I came to know `break` is inherent in `given-when`, to make a fall through I need to use `continue` statement.

When I'm giving input "sweet" it giving output as "Like real people do". Should not is give output as

```
"Honey just put your sweet lips on my lips\n
We should just kiss like real people do"
```

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature "switch";
my $choice = <STDIN>;
my $msg ="";
chomp($choice);
given(lc $choice){
    when('a'){
        $msg = "I had a thought, dear";
    }
    when('b'){
        $msg = "However scary";
    }
    when('c'){
        $msg = "About that night";
    }
    when('d'){
        $msg = "The bugs and the dirt";
    }
    when('e'){
        $msg = "Why were you digging?";
    }
    when('sweet'){
        $msg =  "Honey just put your sweet lips on my lips ";
        continue;
    }
    when('lips'){
        $msg = $msg."\nWe should just kiss like real people do";
    }
    default{
        $msg = "";
    }
}

#print($msg,"\n");
unless($msg eq "") {
    print($msg, "\n");
}else{
    print("Like real People do!\n");
}
```

Comment: Note that the `switch` feature is *experimental* and deemed to have a broken design

Comment: Note that `fc` (not `lc`) should be used for case-insensitive comparisons

Comment: lc is just used here to convert to lower case. Even if I remove it doesn't give right output.@ikegami

Comment: Here are my favorite snippets from the docs: "_Exactly what the EXPR argument to `when` does is hard to describe precisely,_" and "_The rules are far too difficult to understand to be described here._" ... this is your (our) official docs for the feature. Read all of it -- it's "_highly_" experimental and  it will be changed.  I'd suggest to hold out on it, as cool as it may look, and use other techniques instead.

Comment: @UzumakiSaptarshi And the reason you are converting it to lowercase is to do a case-insensitive comparison. For that, you should use `fc`, not `lc`.

Comment: Tip: `$msg = $msg . EXPR;` can be written as `$msg .= EXPR;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[*Note that the smartmatching feature is* experimental *and it's deemed to have a broken design. By extension, so is the switch feature because it uses smartmatching. These should be avoided.*]

Actually, `$msg` contains the empty string.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say switch );
my $choice = "sweet\n";
chomp($choice);
my $msg ="";
given(lc $choice){
    # ...
    when('e'){
        $msg = "Why were you digging?";
    }
    when('sweet'){
        $msg = "Honey just put your sweet lips on my lips\n";
        continue;
    }
    when('lips'){
        $msg .= "We should just kiss like real people do";
    }
    default{
        $msg = "";
    }
}

say ">$msg<";
```

Output:

```
given is experimental at a.pl line 8.
when is experimental at a.pl line 10.
when is experimental at a.pl line 14.
when is experimental at a.pl line 17.
><
```

`continue` causes execution to proceed to the statement following the `when` statement. The next statement is `when('lips'){ ... }`, which does nothing (since `"sweet" ~~ "lips"` is false). The statement after that is `default { $msg = ""; }` which clears `$msg` since no `when` was executed since we continued.

To get the desired result, you would need the following:

```perl
given(lc $choice){
    # ...
    when('e'){
        $msg = "Why were you digging?";
    }
    when('sweet'){
        $msg = "Honey just put your sweet lips on my lips\n";
        continue;
    }
    when($_ ~~ 'sweet' || $_ ~~ 'lips'){
        $msg .= "We should just kiss like real people do";
    }
    default{
        $msg = "";
    }
}
```

Without the experimental switch and smartmatching features, we could use

```perl
for (lc $choice) {
    # ...
    if ($_ eq 'e'){
        $msg = "Why were you digging?";
        last;
    }
    if ($_ eq 'sweet'){
        $msg = "Honey just put your sweet lips on my lips\n";
        last;
    }
    if ($_ eq 'sweet' || $_ eq 'lips'){
        $msg .= "We should just kiss like real people do";
        last;
    }
    $msg = "";
}
```

or

```perl
for (lc $choice) {
    # ...
    if ($_ eq 'e'){
        $msg = "Why were you digging?";
    }
    elsif ($_ eq 'sweet' || $_ eq 'lips'){
        if ($_ eq 'sweet'){
            $msg = "Honey just put your sweet lips on my lips\n";
        }

        $msg .= "We should just kiss like real people do";
    }
    else {
        $msg = "";
    }
}
```